# Detect match failure in JMESPath

Tags: python, jmespath

Using [the Python `jmespath` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jmespath), **how can I distinguish** “matched the expression, the value is `None`” versus “failed to match the expression”?

The `jmespath.search` function returns `None` in two distinct cases:

```python
>>> import jmespath

>>> foo = {'bar': {'lorem': 13, 'ipsum': None}}
>>> repr(jmespath.search('bar.lorem', foo))
'13'
>>> repr(jmespath.search('bar.ipsum', foo))    # Path matches, value None
'None'
>>> repr(jmespath.search('dolor', foo))    # Path does not match
'None'
```

It appears the JMESPath search API **returns `None` in these two distinct cases**. How can the caller know the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it appears **there is no way to distinguish** a match failure versus a success that returns `None`.

There is an [open issue requesting that this should change](https://github.com/jmespath/jmespath.py/issues/113) but for now the answer evidently is  “you can't do that with `jmespath`”.